# What is the minimum set of characters I need to ban to avoid XSS

Tags: xss

I'm writing a simple website and I appreciate my responsibility to avoid my site being used for XSS however I don't really want to spend much time on a detailed or heavy weight solution. If I was to simply ban a list of characters (that people weren't going to need to describe their favourite sausage anyway) what is the smallest list I could get away with?

Users still need the ability to write a paragraph of plain text. So I'll need to keep at least:

```
' " , . ; : - ( )
```

in the hope that some of the less grammatically challenged users can apply them accurately. I was going to start with < and > but searching indicated that, on it's own, isn't necessarily  enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you need to keep

```
' " , . ; : - ( )
```

Doesn't mean you need to keep them as those literal characters. Convert all special characters to their HTML entities (e.g. convert all `<` to `&lt;`

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't just ban characters. Instead prefer to HTML escape any input before outputting it back to the user. See [OWASP XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned the server platform you're working with (.NET, Java, PHP, etc.), and each has slightly different ways of dealing with XSS. However, there are two constants:

1. Always validate your input against a white-list. Don't define what you *won't* allow, rather define what you *will* allow.
2. Always encode your output and do so for the correct language. Most platforms have libraries to do this for you (i.e. [AntiXSS](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) for ASP.NET)

More info on understanding XSS in greater depth here: [OWASP Top 10 for .NET developers part 2: Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/05/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-2.html)